# Derive new coordinates increasing a distance using two known points

Tags: r, coordinates

I try to create a new coordinates point away from 250NM from a known point. I want to keep the trajectory from my starting point and a known point. How could I use this information in order to create a new point, with a known distance :

```
# starting point
lat_0 = 4.842816
lon_0 = 7.017196

#known point
lat_1 = 4.108957
lon_1 = 8.099835
# this point is 78NM away from the starting point
```

I'm using `R` but I could translate a mathematical formula without any problems :).
Thus, I want to create a new point 250NM away, keeping this trajectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)

# test: what are we working with here?
test_df <- data.frame(point = 0:1, lon = c(lon_0, lon_1), lat = c(lat_0, lat_1))
test_df %>% sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% mapview::mapview()
```

[image]

```
# initialise points
point0 <- c(lon_0, lat_0)
point1 <- c(lon_1, lat_1)
#calculate bearing 0 >> 1
bearing0_1 <- geosphere::bearing(point0, point1)
#[1] 123.9916
# Calculate new point with calulated bearing ans distance
# 250 MN = 463000.2 metres
point2 <- as.vector(geosphere::destPoint(p = point0, b = bearing0_1, d = 463000.2))
# test output
rbind(point0, point1, point2) %>% as.data.frame(col.names = c("lon", "lat")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(point = 0:2) %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c(1, 2), crs = 4326) %>% mapview::mapview()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to install some packages in order to try your solution. Uniofrtunately since I tried, R is not working anymore. I'll then mark as resolved once I 'll be able to fix and try it. I saw a lot of formula using bearing / cos / sin, but i was not able to get the bearing, thanks for the ```geosphere``` package tips !

Comment: For the actual solution, you'll only need the geosphere-package. the sf, dplyr and mapview packages are just for testing purposes.